# Correlation matrix plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I want to create a correlation matrix plot, i.e. a plot where each variable is plotted in a scatterplot against each other variable like with `pairs()` or `splom()`. I want to do this with ggplot2. [See here for examples](http://www.r-bloggers.com/five-ways-to-visualize-your-pairwise-comparisons/). The link mentions some code someone wrote for doing this in ggplot2, however, it is outdated and no longer works (even after you swap out the deprecated parts).

One could do this with a loop in a loop and then `multiplot()`, but there must be a better way. I tried melting the dataset to long, and copying the value and variable variables and then using facets. This almost gives you something correct.

```
d = data.frame(x1=rnorm(100),
               x2=rnorm(100),
               x3=rnorm(100),
               x4=rnorm(100),
               x5=rnorm(100))
library(reshape2)
d = melt(d)
d$value2 = d$value
d$variable2 = d$variable

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=value, y=value2)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ variable2)
```

[image]

This gets the general structure right, but only works for the plotting each variable against itself. Is there some more clever way of doing this without resorting to 2 loops?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
library(GGally)

set.seed(42)
d = data.frame(x1=rnorm(100),
               x2=rnorm(100),
               x3=rnorm(100),
               x4=rnorm(100),
               x5=rnorm(100))

# estimated density in diagonal
ggpairs(d)
```

[image]

```
# blank
ggpairs(d, diag = list("continuous"="blank")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Could you explain what is on the diagonal, is this the simple data distribution of x1-x5?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart It is the estimated density. You can turn it off with `diag = list("continuous"="blank")` in `ggpairs()`.

Comment: This is pretty good. Thanks. Now I want just to make the cor data fill out the space better in the upper diagonal, and color it by strength and direction.

Comment: Looks very nice but unfortunately `ggpairs()` is quite slow on 1e6 records.

Answer (score 1):

Using PerformanceAnalytics library :

```
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
chart.Correlation(df, histogram = T, pch= 19)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not ggplot2-based.