# Plot different variable by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data frame

```
ddf <-data.frame(Class=c(rep("pat",times=4),rep("stm",times=4), rep("nst",times=4)),
          Ion= c(rep("pos", times=12), rep("neg", times=12)),
   M1 =runif(24, 5.0, 7.5), M2 =runif(24, 5.0, 7.5), M3 =runif(24, 5.0, 7.5))
```

For each variable `M1` `M2` `M3` I want to correlate `Ion` `Pos` vs `Neg` colour by `Class` and get the correlation coefficient.

I melted

```
library(reshape2)
mm <- melt(ddf, id=c('Class', "Ion"))
```

This in order to use `facet_wrap` to a correlation plot for each variable `M1` and so on. I am not sure how to proceed further

Comment: What type of plot do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to do a Correlation plot

Comment: Is this a dupe [Correlation matrix plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697009/correlation-matrix-plot-with-ggplot2)? See if it can help.

Comment: In part as I want to correlate features by the variable Ion e.g. M1 pos vs M1 neg and so on, but not M1 pos vs M2 pos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the data like this

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Ion) %>%
   mutate(n=1:n()) %>% 
  gather(k, v, -Class, -Ion, -n) %>% 
  spread(Ion,v) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(neg, pos, color=Class)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   facet_grid(~k)
```

[image]

and the correlation coefficient

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Ion) %>%
  mutate(n=1:n()) %>% 
  gather(k, v, -Class, -Ion, -n) %>% 
  spread(Ion,v) %>% 
  split(.$k) %>% 
  map(~cor(.$neg, .$pos))
$M1
[1] -0.01189842

$M2
[1] -0.02646084

$M3
[1] -0.0160802
```