# RStudio - Correlation Matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data table like this:

```
dt <- data.frame(Sector = c("Agriculture", "Manufacture", "Music", "Agriculture", "Manufacture", "Music", "Agriculture", "Manufacture", "Music"), 
    Region = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"), 
    Year = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2010", "2011", "2012"), 
    Number = c("238", "75", "1038", "150", "987", "156", "768", "398", "65"), 
    Population = c("200875", "200875", "200875", "375600", "375600", "375600", "492000", "492000", "492000")
)
dt$Year <- as.numeric(dt$Year)
dt$Number <- as.numeric(dt$Number)
dt$Population <- as.numeric(dt$Population)
```

I want to show the relationship over the years with the correlation matrix for the regions. How can I generate correlation matrix and then plot it with ggplot2? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I am still a little confused when you say "correlation matrix" what variables specifically do you want to correlation? the bottom axis will be Year, but what will be on the Y axis?

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697009/correlation-matrix-plot-with-ggplot2)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=Year, y=Population)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(Region ~ Sector)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying, too.

Comment: I couldn't still solve this question. Do you have any idea?

Comment: not yet, but we should definitely be able to solve this, check this [this link out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697009/correlation-matrix-plot-with-ggplot2)